# add custom popup forms in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Hey Friends im very new to python django.

i am working on a lead management system. which can have certain states.
to change states admin have to fill some required details in a form. i am able to add a button to each row of the table ( next action column ) but how can i open the custom form on click of it.

also i have a single model for lead which can have all the details. can fill some of the fields in one form and the rest in other form.

here is a snapshot of what i am up to thanks.

[image]